# Class with a constructor that loads all sObjects given a user record

Tags: apex, visualforce, constructor

I'm trying to build a class that will gather user information across multiple sObjects. The class needs a constructor that loads all sObjects given a user record. This will be the current user logged in.

I then need to be able to use those on `Visualforce Pages`.

This is what I have so far

```
public class CC_Context 
{ 
    public CC_Context() 
    { 
        boolean userAlreadyExist = true; 
        User retUser = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, ContactId, AccountId FROM User WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserID()]; 
        ContactId retContact = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, AccountId] 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you're not sure where to start, **[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals)** is a much better learning venue. The format here is to ask *specific* questions that include what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I've gone through Trailhead and am still finding it a bit difficult. I completed the beginning develop path.

Comment: Are you trying to get records *owned* by this person? Created? Last Modified?

Comment: Are you trying to learn or is this a business req?

Comment: I'm trying to learn the Developer side and it is a business requirement. I have completed Trail Head Developer path but didn't get that much out of it. I have been finding the Force.com Workbook and Apex Workbook work better for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the running user's Id using the [`UserInfo`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) class:

```
Id runningUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
```

You can query for any number of objects owned by the running user by filtering on the `OwnerId` field:

```
public List<Object1__c> object1Records { get; private set; }
public List<Object2__c> object2Records { get; private set; }
public List<Object3__c> object3Records { get; private set; }
// etc.

public MyController()
{
    object1Records = [SELECT ... FROM Object1__c WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    object2Records = [SELECT ... FROM Object2__c WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    object3Records = [SELECT ... FROM Object3__c WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, I was not sure if I should be using List or creating a map. I often have trouble explaining myself also

Comment: Would it be best to create a Controller Class separate?

Comment: In your case `MyController` and `CC_Context` are synonymous. The class you have started *is* a controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trailhead module and specific chapter about how to display data in VF page

**Trailhead module**

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/units/visualforce_custom_controllers

**Another knowledge article**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205631&type=1

**Summary:** You have use pageblocktable / dataTable to display data in VF page that references the controller method to get the data from the object.

Comment: "You have use pageblocktable / dataTable" - You do not have to. there are many ways to display the data and the pageblocktable and data table are just a few of many tools you can use

Comment: True. I should've said "you can use..."